# Given $y$, is $-\left(\dfrac{x - y}{2}\right)^2$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod x$?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, quadratic-residues

I am trying to find a formula for some [circle packings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing) when the following arose. I am wondering if there is a nice way to find which $y$ yield $-\left(\dfrac{x - y}{2}\right)^2$ a quadratic residue $\pmod x$?

Obviously, $x, y \in \mathbb Z$, and $x > y$. I have tested lots of cases and I can't even find a slight pattern.

The question is equivalent to asking if there exists an $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that
\begin{align*}
    n^2 &\equiv - \left(\dfrac{x - y}{2}\right)^2 \pmod x \\
    -n^2 &\equiv \dfrac{x^2 - 2xy + y^2}{4} \pmod x \\
    -4n^2 &\equiv x^2 - 2xy + y^2 \pmod x 
\end{align*}

Note that the expression on the RHS is a [BQF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_quadratic_form).

Comment: When you say "quadratic residue", do you require it to be relatively prime to the modulus? That point aside, $(\frac{x-y}2)^2$ is clearly a square (and thus a square modulo $x$) regardless of the value of $y$; so the question reduces to asking when $-1$ is a square modulo $x$, which is the case precisely when $x$ has no primes factors that are congruent to $3$ (mod $4$).

Comment: In particular, for any $x$ it is either *all* values of $y$ coprime to $x$, or none of them.